# How to get binary to image from database using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

Convert binary to image using VB.NET from database. I have stored images as binary format in SQL database. How to retrieve those value to image using vb.net

```
bytes = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())
ImgPrv.ImageUrl = bytes
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? HTML images are loaded from URLs, you can't just send the bytes somewhere. Either store the images to the site's folder and use a relative URL, or create a controller (assuming you are using MVC) or an HTTP Handler that will return the bytes when the HTML pages requests the image's URL. This is definitely *not* trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the bytes to a Base64 string and applying that to the image url:

```
bytes = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())
Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
ImgPrv.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," & base64String
```